# Edit selected text in EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have a button and an EditText in my app. When you click on the button, the text from EditText is placed in the database. I need that when clicking on the button, characters Like this AselectedtextA are added to the selected text fragment in the EditText, while preserving the location of the rest of the text from the EditText before and after the selection.

Here is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
ImageView button;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

button = findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String string;
                int startSelection = descEditText.getSelectionStart();
                int endSelection = descEditText.getSelectionEnd();

                string = descEditText.getText().toString();
                string.substring(startSelection, endSelection);

                Spanned s = Html.fromHtml("<b>" + string + "</b>");

                descEditText.setText(s);
            }
        });
    }
```

**activity_Main.xml**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_format_bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I need that when clicking on the button, characters Like this **A**selectedtext**A** are added to the selected text fragment in the EditText, while preserving the location of the rest of the text from the EditText before and after the selection.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, the question doesn't seem to be complicated, but no one gave an answer). In general, I found a suitable crutch... The only thing that confused me a little is the shift that appears when adding characters to the end of the selected text fragment, but since endSelection is int, I just added the number of characters to be added to the position...

```
String s = "AAA";
String e = "BBBB";
int startSelection = descEditText.getSelectionStart();
int endSelection = descEditText.getSelectionEnd();
descEditText.getText().insert(startSelection, s);
descEditText.getText().insert(endSelection + 3, e);
```